# Create dynamic directories based on date in S3 Bucket using Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have the following dataframe schema.

```
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- created_date: date (nullable = true)
```

I want to create directories based on year and month of created_date column in s3 bucket using pyspark. And these directories should contain related data files.

> /year/month/

Is this achievable? If so can help me to find any references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the system time first

```
df = df.withColumn("date_col", F.from_unixtime(F.col("timestamp", "YYYYMMddHH"))

df
.withColumn("year", year(col("date_col")))
.withColumn("month", month(col("date_col")))
.drop("date_col")
.partitionBy("year", "month")
.format("orc")
.save("mypath")
```

Comment: This answer makes another dataframe with year and month columns right? But I want to make directories as /year/month in S3 bucket

Comment: Your folder structure will be like that , but if you want to create sub folders like that - can create two variable i.e year and month and pass them in the file path  dynamically while writing into s3

Comment: When tried your sample code im getting the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'partitionBy'